# Determine if a string contains a substring at a specific position

Tags: c#, string, file, substring

I need to check if a certain filename contains the user speficied substring, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct (I'm new to C#). I am expected to use the asterisks, but I'm unsure how it should be formatted (see my code below).

```
if (fileInfo[i].Name == ("{0} * . * ", partialName) || fileInfo[i].Name == (" * {0}. * ", partialName))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method from `string`, for sample:

```
if (fileInfo[i].Name.Contains(partialName)) 
{
   // your code
}
```

If you want to remove the extension from name, try using the `Path` static class and [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, for sample:

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo[i].Name);

if (fileName.Contains(partialName)) 
{
   // your code
}
```

Now, if you want to ignore case sensitive strings, try using the `IndexOf` method, for sample:

```
if (fileInfo[i].Name.IndexOf(partialName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
{
   // your code
}
```

or apply the Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension to use on `IndexOf`.

Comment: I have to use * 's, plus, using .Contains also checks the file extension, as that is contained in the string.